# How can I type backticks on my Samsung smartphone, which are needed for inline code snippets?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I'm a regular writer here on the site, and I'm more and more working with my smartphone (instead of my computer), but I have an issue: backticks only seem to be usable as accent signs (like "à" or "è"), but writing a simple backtick character "`" seems not to be possible.

What can I do in order to write `inline code`?

I am using a Samsung smartphone with the native Samsung keyboard.

Comment: I have also a Samsung (android) phone and I have access to the "`" character to insert inline code ...

Comment: Same here - samsung, got the key. I use Swiftkey though. That being said, you can also click the bracket button in the editor. If the bracket editor doesn't exist, and you can't find a keyboard with the button, maybe reconsider using a phone or connect a real keyboard instead

Comment: It also exists on Google's keyboard (AKA, Gboard).

Comment: This question is requesting support with a site feature, which makes it on-topic here. Could it also be asked elsewhere (like a Samsung or Android support forum)? Yes. Does that make it off-topic here? No. Our code formatting requires that users type backticks, thus it is fully within our scope to help users figure out how to type backticks on their device in order to make appropriate use of this site's features. Do not close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to be found on the Samsung keyboard, which seems not to be very logical:

At first, there is the general keyboard, containing the "azerty" and all letters, and right down, there's a backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>), but this one is only to be used in order to put accent signs on already typed vowels ("é", "ê", "à", ...).
However, there is also a single backtick character, to be found elsewhere: first click on the <kbd>!#1</kbd> button to open the first page of the symbols keyboard, and then press <kbd>1/2</kbd> to move to the second symbols keyboard, which starts with the backtick character (just underneath the "1" digit).

[image: screenshot of keyboard]

Comment: Why isn't that logical? It's in the symbols part of the keyboard, and it's in the second set because it isn't a character most users will need to type very often.

Comment: What's not logical is the utter lack of [a freehand circle in the image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/194720) ;-)

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: if it's that logical, then where is the forward tick `"´"`? :-)

Answer (score 8):

Using the default Android keyboard ([Gboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gboard)):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: GBoard is not the "default android keyboard". There's no such thing. It might be what your particular device came with, but it's not standard everywhere, by any means.

Comment: In fact, this question is about a Samsung device so the default keyboard is almost certainly _not_ GBoard, but instead Samsung Keyboard

Comment: @MikeM.: I mean the default on stock android (i.e. android ONE)